# How do I model deletion in an EF Core many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I've [followed the docs](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) for setting up my many-to-many relationship, using a join table that is exposed as an entity.

But the docs don't mention what I should do about deletion.

So for example, a `Student` has many teachers, and a `Teacher` has many students. The join entity/table is `StudentTeacher`.

The join table/entity:

```
public class StudentTeacher {
  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  public Student Student { get; set; }
  public int TeacherId { get; set; }
  public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

The config for the join table/entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentTeacher>()
  .HasOne(b => b.Teacher)
  .WithMany(b => b.StudentTeachers)
  .HasForeignKey(b => b.TeacherId)
  .IsRequired()
  .OnDelete(/* ... what goes here? ...*/);

modelBuilder.Entity<StudentTeacher>()
  .HasOne(b => b.Student)
  .WithMany(b => b.StudentTeachers)
  .HasForeignKey(b => b.StudentId)
  .IsRequired()
  .OnDelete(/* ... what goes here? ...*/);
```

What do I use in `OnDelete()`? And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems confusing at first to model the join table, because <=EF6 didn't need it. But it's actually simple.

When deleting a `Teacher` entity, you need to delete its relationships to all `Student` entities. When deleting a `Student` entity, you need to delete its relationships to all `Teacher` entities.

So join entities must always be `CASCADE` deleted.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is what I did most of my relationship tables. What about that I don't want to delete relationships on db side? I need to log or archive some important relationships. In this teacher student example this is not necessary, but I have that kind of situation. What would you do or suggest anything? @grokky

Comment: @kizilsu I suppose the easiest is to set a trigger on the db and create an audit log that way. Or, map it in EF, and create an entry every time you delete.

Comment: Doesn't that contradict the *Important 2* part of the other answer? It's stated that both linked entities can't be cascading the deletion and at least one of them needs to be set to restricted behavior. I agree with your reasoning but when I tested, I got error updating database (just as the other answer suggests).

Answer (score 3):

> `.OnDelete(/* ... what goes here? ...*/);`

You should specify here what DB must do with child records (in `StudentTeacher`) when parent records (in `Student` or `Teacher`) is deleted: delete too (`Cascade`) or prohibit and throw error (`Restrict`) if corresponding child record exists. With `Restrict` you must manually delete child records before deleting parent one.

But only you can decide what action must be applied for each relationship - this is your application, we don't know all requirements to it.

**Important**: with `Cascade`, deleting, say, `Teacher` will affect (delete) only records in `StudentTeacher` (with corresponding `TeacherId`), but `Students` will be keep intact.

**Important 2**: In MS SQL Server (you didn't wrote what DB engine you are using), you can set only one to `Cascade` (other should be `Restrict`), or you will receive error when applying migration (*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint _some_name_ on table _some_table_ may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.*)

Comment: I already know the difference between the delete modes, but, this is a special case, because it's for a join table. Unlike <EF6, in EF Core we need to explicitly create a "join entity" to model the join table. I don't think this is app-dependent, it is probably the same in every case. PS I used cascade delete because it makes sense to me, but wanted to know if that is correct.

Comment: This is exactly one of my problems that should I use cascade or not? I did cascade, but cascade delete operation is running on db side, and if there is no trigger you wont get back your records. So, I did deletion process on when user update the enrollement table like removing a teacher to a student or vice verse. Thus, I can track the operations and save the records. May be you can also do like that @grokky

Comment: @kizilsu Dmitry's answer is correct and gives good background to the problem. But to decide which delete mode to use, see my answer as well.